# ASP MVC ActionLink causes invalid URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, urlencode, actionlink

Using the standard route pattern

```
{controller}/{action}/{code}
```

and then a standard ActionLink in my view

```
<%: ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { code = item.Code }) %>
```

When the user has entered "N/A" as their code I see the following URL

```
http://localhost/AbsenceCode/Details/N/A
```

When I expect to see this

```
http://locahost/AbsenceCode/Details/N%2FA
```

Also, if the user has "A:B" as their code I see the correct URL (colon is url escaped) but I get a "400 bad request" from the server.

Does anyone have solutions to these problems?  I cannot force the customer to use URL safe characters only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution, source code is available here:
https://mrpmorris.blogspot.com/2012/08/asp-mvc-encoding-route-values.html

Comment: Is it this? -> http://mrpmorris.blogspot.mx/2012/08/asp-mvc-encoding-route-values.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { code = Url.Encode(item.Code) }) &>
```

Comment: Forward slash is a valid url character so it won't get escaped.  Also, it seems that any %xx escape characters are seen as bad requests by ASP MVC